# Website auditing in chrome browser showing different results for different devices

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension

I am testing website performance using chrome's audit extension on different devices.

The performance results are different for different devices for the same website. I ran tests on my machine, macbook and dell laptop.

Why the results are different every time? And does these tests run on local device or is it cloud based?

Comment: may you elabroate more about your issue? maybe with some screenshots, are you testing an app engine application?

Comment: I am running an audit from my chrome browser for a website cerebry.co, my question is when i do the audit on my macbook it is showing more performance and on my dell it is showing less permormance, the audit runs based on the local machine i am trying with or the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

As you are running test using chrome extension which runs in local machine, so it will be slightly different for different platforms and it will also depends on the internet connectivity.

For better and more reliable testing of website, it is better to use simulator or on server based service because all the users might not be privileged of having better device or internet connection.

There are many server/cloud based services. Below are two of them which I use.

1) You can use web.dev using [Google's Lighthouse](https://web.dev/measure/?gclid=CjwKCAjwte71BRBCEiwAU_V9hyNUi_hhhCbmqEsj2IWtWnJcK0jHijflbBQov9zVU6zm42zQQ7ef9BoCCWkQAvD_BwE) 
*All tests are run using a simulated mobile device, throttled to a fast 3G network & 4x CPU slowdown.*

2) You can use [webpagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org/). On this platform you can create your own simulation here.

Answer (score 0):

This because the hardware and the CPU load can affect your results, even some chrome extensions can affect the performance.

I ran some tests over cerebry.co and I couldn't notice any significant difference between tests,I performed my tests on power save mode and in high performance mode, switching between WiFi 5GHz and 2.4GHz bands, with cache disabled.

-- Macbook 12 PRO MID 2012 i7 3rd gen 16GB ram SSD (3.4s - 5.7s)

-- HP Chromebook i7 8th gen 16GB ram SSD (3.2s - 4s)

-- ASUS ROG i5 7th gen 12GB ram NVME (3s- 3.4s)

-- HP ENVY i5 4th gen 12GB ram HDD 5.4K RPM (3.2s- 3.7s)

Maybe with older or slower HW I can experience a performance degradation.